# Angular 11 how to get if all items in child array includes items in another given array

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, angular11

I have the following complex array:

```
private _questionTypes: QuestionType[] = <QuestionType[]>[
        {
            name: 'YesNoN/A',
            displayText: 'Yes / No / N/A',
            questionTypeItem: <QuestionTypeAttribute[]>[
                {
                    displayText: 'Yes',
                    color: 'green',
                },
                {
                    displayText: 'No',
                    color: 'red',
                },
                {
                    displayText: 'N/A',
                    color: '#FFBF00',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            displayText: 'Completed / In Progress / Not Started',
            name: 'NotStartedInProgressCompletedDummyOption',

            questionTypeItem: <QuestionTypeAttribute[]>[
                {
                    displayText: 'Completed',
                    color: 'green',
                },
                {
                    displayText: 'In Progress',
                    color: '#FFBF00',
                },
                {
                    displayText: 'Not Started',
                    color: 'red',
                }
            ]
        }
```

I want to find the index of the array where all items in the 'questionTypeItem' array contains values from a given test array. i.e

```
titles = ['Yes','No','N/A']
```

I want to check which item matches all items from the titles array and get the 'displayText' proprty expected value in this example is

I tried something like below but didnt worked:

```
    return this._questionTypes.find(
        x => x.questionTypeItem.every(item => item.displayText.includes(titles))
    ).map(yy => yy.displayText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const selectedItem = this._questionTypes
        .find(q => q.questionTypeItem.every(item => titles.includes(item.displayText)));
```

The above script worked for me